# Computing output of an excel formula with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains a formula. I am wondering what the best way would be to use the formula and compute outputs based on a given input.

My first inclination would be to load the spread into PHPExcel object and set the values of each cell involved in the formula to a given input and then finally read the result.

EDIT: I have attempted getting the computed value of the formula with:

```
getCalculatedValue()
```

I run this method on the cell that should contain the computed value of the spread 'as is' but it's spitting out undefined offset errors for Excel5.php and MathTrig.php and an incorrect result:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 437 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bang/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php on line 5679

Notice: Undefined offset: 438 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bang/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php on line 5679

Notice: Undefined offset: 439 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bang/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php on line 5679

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bang/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/MathTrig.php on line 1171
```

Formula and stack trace of it from the debug in PHPExcel is:

```
Value is =SUMIF(Sheet3!A1:H530,"=212410000",Sheet3!H1:H530)
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => Sheet3!A1
            [reference] => Sheet3!A1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => Sheet3!H530
            [reference] => Sheet3!H530
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => :
            [reference] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => Value
            [value] => "=212410000"
            [reference] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => Sheet3!H1
            [reference] => Sheet3!H1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => Sheet3!H530
            [reference] => Sheet3!H530
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => :
            [reference] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [type] => Operand Count for Function SUMIF()
            [value] => 3
            [reference] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [type] => Function
            [value] => SUMIF(
            [reference] => 
        )

)
```

The line from Excel5.php that is triggering the error is:

```
    // offset: 1; size: 2; one-based index to definedname record
                $definedNameIndex = self::_GetInt2d($formulaData, 1) - 1;
                // offset: 2; size: 2; not used
                $data = $this->_definedname[$definedNameIndex]['name']; // errors here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the calculation engine in debug mode to get a lot more detail about what it is doing to help diagnose such problems:

```
$cell = 'C3';
//  enable debugging
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->writeDebugLog = true;

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
echo '<b>'.$cell.' Value is </b>'.$formulaValue."<br />\n";

$calculate = false;
try {
    $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->parseFormula($formulaValue,$sheet->getCell($cell));
    echo '<b>Parser Stack :-</b><pre>';
    print_r($tokens);
    echo '</pre>';
    $calculate = true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "PARSER ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";

    echo '<b>Parser Stack :-</b><pre>';
    print_r($tokens);
    echo '</pre>';
}

if ($calculate) {
    //  calculate
    try {
        $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";

        echo '<h3>Evaluation Log:</h3><pre>';
        print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->debugLog);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

No guarantees, because I'll need to test it a bit more, but modify line 1171 in the Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/MathTrig.php file

This line currently reads

```
$returnValue += $sumArgs[$key];
```

change it to

```
$returnValue += $sumArgs[$key % count($sumArgs)];
```

It's assuming that the number of cells in the criteria range (Sheet3!A1:H530 in your case) matches the number of cells in the summed range (Sheet3!H1:H530) which clearly isn't the case when the criteria references 8 columns and 530 rows while the summed range only references 530 rows in a single column.

**EDIT #2**

While above Edit suggestion will fix the error, it'll return the wrong result. If you specify A1:H530 as your criteria, but only H1:H530 as your summed values in MS Excel, it only tests the first column (to match the potential number of summed results) and ignores columns B-H in the criteria.

A quick fix might be to modify lines 1161 which read:

```
if (empty($sumArgs)) {
    $sumArgs = $aArgs;
}
```

to

```
if (empty($sumArgs)) {
    $sumArgs = $aArgs;
} elseif (count($aArgs) > count($sumArgs)) {
    $aArgs = array_slice($aArgs,0,count($sumArgs));
}
```

and revert line 1171 (now 1173) back to

```
$returnValue += $sumArgs[$key];
```

I still need to check if flattenArray orders the cells correctly, but that's going to be a closer fix

**EDIT #3**

It'll take longer to fix PHPExcel's calc engine to handle mismatched criteria/summed arrays (my fix above won't work because PHPExcel flattens by row, while this need sto be flattened by column) - but as a temporary fix change your formula to use just one column in the criteria range

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately the errors captured in the 'calculate' block are the same and no more specific. Notice: Undefined offset in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bang/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/MathTrig.php on line 1171. Additionally the reader errors for Excel5.php always print on loading of the file into memory.

Comment: It is not triggering the catch block where the cell value is calculated.

Comment: Sounds more like it's a reader problem than a formula problem then. Is the formula and the stack being dumped by this code?

Comment: Well the error in MathTrig.php is referring to a line in the SUMIF function which is the formula im using. It is. Answer edited to include this.

Comment: I'm concerned that the SUMIF formula is trying to do something with a cell that hasn't been correctly read by whatever is causing those read errors - but I want to verify that the SUMIF formula is being parsed correctly

Comment: Have added the error line from the Excel5.php to the question.

Comment: It'll take longer to fix PHPExcel's calc engine to handle mismatched criteria/summed arrays (my fix above won't work because PHPExcel flattens by row, while this need sto be flattened by column) - but as a temporary fix change your formula to use just one column in the criteria range

Comment: No problem thank you for the assistance! Your engagement here is very encouraging to users of this lib. Changing the criteria range to one column will work for now. If you edit your answer to include your last comment, I am willing to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you do toArray you can:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index);
$arrExcelObject = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

The toArray function is documented in the code:

```
public function toArray($nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = true, $formatData = true, $returnColumnRef = false)
```

So second arg to indicate you want to calc from the formula, by default is set to true.

Comment: Hi so this is like getCalculateValue, except that it returns an array of all cells with their respective formula computed values, correct? I get the following errors when I run it however:

Undefined offset: PHPExcel/Calculation/MathTrig.php
Undefined offset: PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php

Comment: it will return an array of rows from your xls. Not sure about the error without any information. But I suggest you try xls file first instead of xlsx.

Comment: The input is .xls currently. Not sure what information I can provide other than the location of the errors. The undefined offsets refer to the following lines in PHPExcel: [Excel5.php - 5679] and [MathTrig.php - 1171] if that is of any help? I know there are limitations on the PHPExcel calculation engine.

Comment: the calc can't do custom excel macro. The PHPExcel calc is really poor but you may want to check your data/formula in the xls. I run PHPExcel every week without problem with simple calc. If everything failed I think you have to copy the value to the new row.

Comment: I have found the part of the formula that is triggering the error in the MathTrig.php. Its a 'SUMIF' that tries to match a string in the format: =SUMIF(Sheet2!RANGE,"STRING",Sheet2!RANGE). All the values compute correctly in the excel.

Comment: I have updated the question with a reproduce for the errors im getting. I would have thought that this was quite a common formula that someone like yourself must come across if you are using it every week?

Comment: I use it to import data, I am not doing special thing with it, the excel I got is very straight forward. I know formula with vb script function will not work.

Comment: Okay no problem. Thanks for your advice :) I'll keep hacking on it in the meantime and post back here my findings if i crack it.